# how to create types in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I tried Create type schema."objectname" is table of number;

It did not work
please help

Comment: Can you elaborate on "did not work"?  Was there an error message?  Did it create something unexpected instead?  Or what?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried taking a look at [the Oracle documentation for CREATE TYPE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8001.htm)?